# Embedded Google Calendar API

Tags: vb.net, api, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

o/

to cut a long story short i am working on a project in .NET for Google Calendar API. the issue i'm having i want to be able to retrieve information from a publicly available Calendar document however its embedded and i don't have the ID for it so i cant connect to it via the API. Does anyone know how i can actively retrieve the data via the API or get the ID so i can connect normally?

Im quite new to the API scene but have done some JSON Parsing and work with the Google Sheets API so please keep it kind of simple :P

Thanks guys and happy holidays... why am i working on an API Xmas day -.-

Answer (score 0):

To get the id of the embedded calendar via chrome you can inspect the page, find the iframe element and get the src attribute.

In the sample below the value of src is "en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com". The decoded value is "en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com"

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com"     style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">    </iframe>
```

Below is the sample call to get the Calendar details of the calendar id using the [calendar api explorer](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get). (You can explore other APIs by clicking the link)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com?fields=description%2Cetag%2Cid%2Ckind%2Clocation%2Csummary&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response:**

```
{

 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"wPB4sv3SXX_TNjlIyBWrKwcZTHg/nUiLfyW1Tclq4NFare2eNmH24do\"",
 "id": "en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com",
 "summary": "Holidays in United States",
 "description": "Holidays and Observances in United States"
}
```